# Terraform try to pull not defined provider

Tags: terraform, databricks, azure-databricks

Every time I perfomr `terraform init` tf try to pull from registry quite strange provider which do not exit.

Error:

```
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│ 
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/databricks: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named
│ registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/databricks
│ 
│ Did you intend to use databrickslabs/databricks? If so, you must specify that source address in each module which requires that provider. To see which modules are currently depending on
│ hashicorp/databricks, run the following command:
│     terraform providers
╵
```

This providere is quite strange combination of 2 providers.

My tf file:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 2.65"
    }
    databrick = {
      source  = "databrickslabs/databricks"
      version = "0.3.7"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 0.14.9"
}


provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

provider "databrick" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "TerraformResourceGroup"
  location = "westeurope"
}

resource "azurerm_databricks_workspace" "databrick" {
  name                = "terraform-databrick"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  sku                 = "trial"

  tags = {
    "env"         = "rnd"
    "provisoning" = "tf"
  }

}

data "databricks_node_type" "smallest" {
  local_disk = true

}

data "databricks_spark_version" "latest_lts" {
  long_term_support = true

}

resource "databricks_cluster" "cluster" {
  cluster_name            = "terraform-cluster"
  spark_version           = data.databricks_spark_version.latest_lts.id
  node_type_id            = data.databricks_node_type.smallest.id
  autotermination_minutes = 20

  spark_conf = {
    "spark.databricks.cluster.profile" : "singleNode"
    "spark.master" : "local[*]"
  }

  custom_tags = {
    "type"        = "SingleNode"
    "env"         = "rnd"
    "provisoning" = "tf"
  }
}
```

I was looking for some kind of 'verbose' flag, so I could find why it is trying to pull this kind of provider and from where it is coming.
Sadly I was able only to be able to find up that this issue is comming from 'data' and below part of my file.

All my knowlage is based on this docs [Data brick cluster](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/cluster) and this learning material [Terraform Azure](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/azure-build?in=terraform/azure-get-started)
Thank you in advace all of your help.

Comment: You have a typo in your provider configuration. `databrick = {` should be `databricks = {`

Comment: That was that. Please create aswer so I can mark it as resolved :)
There were 2 typos in providers name.

Comment: Questions that are just typos aren't particularly useful for others who come across the question/answer so typically we just close them (there's a close vote reason for typos) and I've voted accordingly. Glad you got your problem fixed though.